# In Electron, all Cookies within the page are automatically cleared each time BrowserView is loaded

Tags: html, node.js

I got confused: Every time I open BrowserView, BrowserView automatically caches previous Cookies.

What I need: Every time I open the BrowserView window, I need to log in again, instead of remembering the last Cookiess by default.

I have experienced many methods, the following clearCookies(url) but does not work, please how to implement

```
//main.js
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();

  ipcMain.on("create-linkweb", createLinkWebWindow);

  app.on("activate", () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow();
    }
  });
});
```

```
//main.js
function createLinkWebWindow() {
  let newWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    parent: win,
    width: 850,
    height: 500,
    webPreferences: {
      webSecurity: false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
    show: false,
    frame: false,
  });

  const view = new BrowserView({
    webPreferences: {},
  });

  newWindow.loadFile("renderer/pages/linkweb.html");

  newWindow.setBrowserView(view);
  view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 35, width: 850, height: 465 });
  view.webContents.loadURL("http://www.exmaple.com");

  view.webContents.on("did-start-loading", () => {
    const url = "http://www.example.com";
    clearCookies(url);
  });

}
```

```
function clearCookies(url) {
  const cookieStore = session.defaultSession.cookies;

  cookieStore
    .get({ url: url })
    .then((cookies) => {
      cookies.forEach((cookie) => {
        console.log(url, cookie.name);
        cookieStore.remove(url, cookie.name).catch((error) => {
          console.error(`Failed to remove cookie: ${error}`);
        });
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(`Failed to get cookies: ${error}`);
    });
}
```

I tried to set the Session cookie to null when BrowserView was being built, but it didn't work.

I want to have to log in again every time I open a window.